# Windows persistent route gateway unavailable so default route used

Tags: windows, router

I have a server with 2 NIC's. Default route is added to primary NIC only, as usual. Persistent route added to route table to force traffic to a certain destination subnet out the second NIC. It appears that when the gateway of the second nic is down, or even set to wrong ip address, and traffic needs to use this route to reach the listed destination, after a time it will time out and use the default gateway.

Can you confirm this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That is standard routing behaviour.

A routing table will try and match the most specific route available - In this case when its working via the primary NIC.  When that route is not present it will match the next available route which is the catch-all.

I don't "DO" Windows, but you may be able to hack around this behaviour either with firewall or with another metric for the destination subnet with a lower priority - either of these methods would work under Linux and other routing software.